# What is the proper order for watching the El Hazard series?

Tags: el-hazard

The *[El Hazard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El-Hazard)* series, written by Ryoe Tsukimura and directed by Hiroki Hayashi, consists of two OVA series and two TV anime:

**OVA**

- [*El Hazard: The Magnificent World*](http://myanimelist.net/anime/117/El_Hazard__The_Magnificent_World)
- [*El Hazard 2: The Magnificent World*](http://myanimelist.net/anime/118/El_Hazard_2__The_Magnificent_World)

**TV Series**

- [*El Hazard: The Wanderers*](http://myanimelist.net/anime/116/El_Hazard__The_Wanderers)
- [*El-Hazard: The Alternative World*](http://myanimelist.net/anime/115/El_Hazard__The_Alternative_World)

How are these different productions related? What is the best order for someone to enjoy them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chronologically by release, it goes:

1. The first OVA, *El Hazard: The Magnificent World* (OVA1, 1995)
2. The first TV series, *El Hazard: The Wanderers* (TV1, 1995)
3. The second OVA, *El Hazard 2: The Magnificent World* (OVA2, 1997)
4. The second TV series, *El-Hazard: The Alternative World* (TV2, 1998)

The *Wanderers* TV series (TV1) is of a seperate continuity (basically a retelling of the OVA series, but aimed at a younger demographic) to the two OVAs (OVA1 + OVA2).

The *Alternative World* TV series (TV2) is set after the second *Magnificent World* OVA.

So chronologically by story, it goes:

1. *Magnificent World* (OVA1) ⇒ 2. *Magnificent World* (OVA2) ⇒ 3. *Alternative World* (TV2)

⤜ `|| ...somewhere completely unrelated... ||` *The Wanderers* (TV1) ⤛